# json not reaching the remote server

Tags: android, json, linux, digital-ocean

I am trying to run an application on remote server when i try to register a user it return this.
The same application is working fine on establishing a server on my Laptop. I want to know if I am missing any dependency on LINUX to recieve JSON on my server end.

> org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

My Android Activity is as follows :-

```
      private void registerUser(final String reg_FullName_value ,final String  reg_Username_value, final String reg_Email_value, final String  reg_Password_value)
    {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "register";
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppURLs.URL , new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                Log.d("Response",response);
                hideDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Regestered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        setContentView(R.layout.login);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Regestered.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
               }catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Some problem occur: check NetworK" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "register");
                params.put("FullName", reg_FullName_value );
                params.put("Username", reg_Username_value);
                params.put("Email", reg_Email_value);
                params.put("Password", reg_Password_value);
                return params;


}

        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr, tag_string_req);
    }
```

The PHP file to handle this response is this :-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
if(isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '')
{
  $tag = $_POST['tag'];
  require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
  $db = new DB_Functions();
  $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);
  //registration
  if ($tag == 'register')
  {
    $name = $_POST['FullName'];
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $user = $db->storeUser($name, $username , $email , $password);
    if ($user)
    {
      $response["error"] = FALSE;
      $response["error_msg"] = "Registration Successful";
      echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
      $response["error"] = TRUE;
      $response["error_msg"] = "Registration Failed";
      echo json_encode($response);
    }
  }
  //login
  else if ($tag == 'login')
  {
    $user = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $user_check = $db->getUserByUserAndPassword($user , $password);
    if ($user_check != false)
    {
      $response["Success"] = TRUE;
      $response["error"] = FALSE;
      $response["error_msg"] = "User Exists";
      $response["Username"] = $user;
      echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {
      $response["error"] = TRUE;
      $response["error_msg"] = "No such User";
      echo json_encode($response);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    {
      $response["error"] = TRUE;
      $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect token or password!";
      echo json_encode($response);
    }
  }
}
else
{
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Recieved No Data";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I am using a droplet to make a cloud server. I need to know what is the reason behind the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(response)){
     Toast.makeText(this, "response is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return;
}
Log.d("Response",response);
```

You should check response is not null and not an empty string first.

If you response is null ,your `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);` will get an exception .

Comment: Yes I am getting an empty response from the server. Though the files on my computer and the droplet are exactly the same. But on my local computer as server it works fine

Comment: So you should check your response first .Then parse your JSON data.@Cyborg

Comment: I think the problem is the with the droplet I have opened a support ticket the digital ocean may assist me with this. Thanks friend.

Comment: That wan't useful friend

Comment: I want to know why I am getting an empty response?

Comment: Okay, I thought that you know that you response is empty and you can deal with it .@Cyborg

Comment: And I found the reason of your code .Isn't it ?@Cyborg

Comment: Friend I already knew that I am getting an empty response. I want to know why I am getting that? Can you help me with it.